# Cant apply Dynamic routing whit nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, next.js

I 'm learning nextJS and I'm stuck whit Dynamic Routes.
I created a folder call "details" inside `/pages` and there I create a `[slug].js`, and in my home page put the link tag inside a map function.
The problem is that it doesn't work. Is not open the `[slug].js` file.. why I 'm doing wrong?

Thank!
this is my code:

**Home.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Context from "../../config/Context";
import Link from "next/link";

const Home = () => {
    const context = React.useContext(Context);

    return context.events.map(event => (
      <ul>
        <li key={event.id}>
          <Link href="/details/[slug]" as={`/details/${event.slug}`}>
              <a>{event.slug}</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    ));
  };

export default Home;
```

**pages/details/[slug].js**

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default () => {
  const router = useRouter()

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Blog post</h1>
      <p>Post id: {router.query.id}</p>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi, it looks good to me, are you sure context contains correct data?

Comment: @German, yes I' m sure...

Comment: based on your file name ```pages/details/[slug].js```, ```router.query.slug``` is correct code. param name should match.